# AutoLISP for 3D tracks rotates one but not the other

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I have this autolisp for 3D drawing in autocad. It makes two tracks that go under the body of a tank, and I was able to rotate one of them to the desired position, and as you can see below, I have the same command for rotation for both tracks:

```
 ; Rotate the first object by 90 degrees in Y
  (command "rotate3d" e1 "" "Y" ip 90)
```

and

```
 ; Rotate the second object by 90 degrees in Y
  (command "rotate3d" e2 "" "Y" ip 90)
```

, however it is not rotating both the tracks, just one.
Take a look below:

```
(defun tracks (ip /)
  (command "ucs" '(0 -30 2.5) "")
  (setq
    ip2 '(0 0 0)
    p1 (rpoint3d ip 15.166 4.5 0)
    p2 (rpoint3d ip 17.166 2.5 0)
    p3 (rpoint3d ip 17.166 -2.5 0)
    p4 (rpoint3d ip 15.166 -4.5 0)
    p5 (rpoint3d ip -15.166 -4.5 0)
    p6 (rpoint3d ip -17.166 -2.5 0)
    p7 (rpoint3d ip -17.166 2.5 0)
    p8 (rpoint3d ip -15.166 4.5 0)
  )
  (command "color" 5 "" )
  (command "pline" p1 p2 p3 p4 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p1 "" )
  (setq e1 (entlast))
  (command "offset" 1 e1 ip2 "")
  (setq e2 (entlast))
  (command "extrude" e1 "" 6 "")
  (setq e1 (entlast))
  (command "extrude" e2 "" 6 "")
  (setq e2 (entlast))
  (command "subtract" e1 "" e2 "")
  (setq e1 (entlast))
  (command "ucs" '(0 34 -9.5) "")
  
  (command "mirror3d" e1 "" ip ipx ipy "n")
  
  ; Rotate the first object by 90 degrees in Y
  (command "rotate3d" e1 "" "Y" ip 90)
  
  ; Rotate the second object by 90 degrees in Y
  (command "rotate3d" e2 "" "Y" ip 90)

  (princ)
)
```

I appreciate all and any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: After the subtract operation, the entity pointer `e2` will likely point to an erased entity.